# Combining two lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> NOTE:  **prohibited from using ++ in your code.**

```
join :: ([t],[t]) -> [t]
```

which takes a pair of lists of some type t, (xs,ys) and returns a single list that contains all the elements
some testcases :

```
join ([],[])) "==" [])
join ([],[5,6,5])) "==" [5,6,5]
join ([7],[5,6,5])) "==" [7,5,6,5]
join ([3,7],[5,6,5])) "==" [3,7,5,6,5]
join ("be","happy")) "==" "behappy"
```

This is what I currently have

```
module Sum where 
join :: ([t],[t]) -> [t]
join x y = [ z | z <- x, a <- y]
```

the error I get is

```
Sum.hs:3:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[t]'
                  with actual type `[t0] -> [a0]'
    * The equation(s) for `join' have two arguments,
      but its type `([t], [t]) -> [t]' has only one
    * Relevant bindings include
        join :: ([t], [t]) -> [t] (bound at Sum.hs:3:1)
  |
3 | join x y = [ z | z <- x, a <- y]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Sum.hs:3:23: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `([t], [t])'
    * In the expression: x
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: z <- x
      In the expression: [z | z <- x, a <- y]
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: ([t], [t]) (bound at Sum.hs:3:6)
        join :: ([t], [t]) -> [t] (bound at Sum.hs:3:1)
  |
3 | join x y = [ z | z <- x, a <- y]
  |                       ^
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have a type error in the arguments of the function:

```
join :: ([t],[t]) -> [t]
join x y = [ z | z <- x, a <- y]
```

it should be:

```
join :: ([t],[t]) -> [t]
join (x,y) = [ z | z <- x, a <- y]
```

but that will return to you:

```
  join' ("hello", "world")
=> "hhhhheeeeellllllllllooooo"
```

because list comprehension combines all values from the two lists, so, don't use it in this case. Instead:

Why don't you use recursion over the structure of `(,)` and `[]`? it should be easy as:

```
join :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]
join ([], ys) = ys
join (xs, []) = xs
join ((x:xs), ys) = x : (join (xs, ys))
```

example:

```
join ("hello", "world")
=> "helloworld"
```

Answer (score 1):

They want you to implement `++`.

If you could use `++`, the implementation would be:

```
join (x, y) = x ++ y
```

Comment: I saw that before the edit which is why I wrote the answer the way I did.